# Why chrome developer console doesn't list any property/method?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, prototypal-inheritance

If I define an empty object via `var a = new Object()` I implicitly inherit from the `Object.prototype` object.

Why when I dump this newly created object through chrome console it gives back only this:

> Object {}

And not some sort of expandable tree with the whole list of properties/methods inherited from Object.prototype?

Comment: `console.log(Object.prototype)` --> `Object {}`.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding prototypes to the base Object, that's used for everything everywhere and can cause you massive headaches. Please use a different type for your new objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "dump"? If you `console.log` it, you *can* expand the tree by clicking on the prototype chain - you will see `Object.prototype`

Comment: It looks like you are talking about the "summary" view (don't actually know how it's called). This will only show own properties I believe.

Comment: scragar of course it's a trivial piece of code

Answer (score 2):

Many built-in prototype items such as `Object.prototype.toString` are *non-enumerable*. This means that a `for..in` loop will ignore them, and I believe `Object.keys()` will not return them either.

Since that is what the console uses to traverse objects, these non-enumerable properties will be invisible.

Comment: no, the console does show non-enumerable keys as well. Why do you think it uses a `for in` loop?

Comment: That's correct Bergi. If I am right, non-enumerable props/methods are displayed in a lighter colour than the enumerable ones